# How to check if a role is automatically managed by an integration?

Tags: discord.py

I want to check if a role is "automatically managed by an integration. It cannot be manually assigned to members or deleted". Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Get the role object and check its [managed](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Role.managed) attribute.

Example `my_role.managed` which will be a `bool` aka `True` if it is managed.

You can get the role object by using [bot.get_role(integer)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_role) where bot is your bot/client instance.